# Cannot search Arqade mobile site from Nintendo 3DS

Tags: bug, status-declined, search, mobile-site, browser-support

I was playing a game on my 3DS and wanted to get an answer about it, so I figured I'd use the 3DS's web browser to access Arqade. Overall the mobile site works quite well on the 3DS (though it is not enabled by default), except that **it is impossible to perform a search.** The search form does not have a submit button, and the 3DS's browser does not have any “return key to submit” equivalent operation as far as I have found.

Can we have a search button which is provided when the `User-Agent` is the 3DS's browser, or better yet when it is not one which is known to support submission of buttonless forms?

(I recognize that this is a Stack Exchange-wide facility; I'm posting here because this is the community which is likely to be interested in this improvement.)

Comment: This is a dupe, and is also [status-declined]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/no-search-button-accessibility-problem

Comment: @YiJiang - That's old enough that I might argue it should be revisited.  Also, I think 3DS is *extremely* relevant to this site.

Comment: I've offered a bounty on the MSO question.

Comment: Is there no "Go" button under the keyboard? There is one for URL input: http://cdn.ripten.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/3ds-browser.jpg

Comment: @Resorath There is a button under the keyboard, but all it does is exit the keyboard and save your text into the actual form field — it doesn't submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The mobile version of the site is now [considered deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041), and is in the process of being replaced with the main version of the site (utilising responsive design principles to provide a decent experience on mobile):

> Instead of maintaining both of these, we’re going to unship the mobile view and opt everyone into the responsive views by default. Along the way, we plan on improving the responsive views we show.
> <sub>- Aaron Shekey - Product Designer, Stack Overflow</sub>

---

Also note that the 3DS browser is not one of the browsers supported by Stack Exchange:

> #### Which browsers are supported?
>
> **We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use.** This does not include beta, developer, nightly, canary, or any other pre-release versions of browsers, which are not supported.
> <sub>- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)</sub>

Please also see the [visualisation of supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/).